# why can't I make a footer that works, in css?

Tags: html, css, footer

http://cssdesk.com/kBNHh

okay, so there's my css + html.

The problem is the footer. Don't know how to work it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I'm still getting the thing where the text ( in div called child 2 i.e. main body of text) overlaps the footer if I insert too much text in the div. Why can't I keep anything from overlapping the footer?  I've tried putting the footer outside of the wrapper ( field), I've tried everything. But the text just overlaps the footer when you have too much of it. Should I try padding again? Edit: nope, still doesn't work.

Footer is called Child 4 ( even though it isn't the child of "field" i.e. main wrapper in my html).

I've been to several websites, with great details. Even tried some of the css provided there. But as soon as I edit it to fit my plan, the footer stops functioning. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post an image of your layout wishes? Its hard to understand what you are want to do...

Comment: I'll bet (without looking at the problem in detail) that this is an issue that will be helped in large part by the use of `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a positioning format called absolute. This means that each div is positioned exactly on the screen with the coordinates you have defined, the other divs (that are also absolutely positioned) do not affect the position of any of the others.

If you use position:relative instead of position:absolute then it might get you along the right lines.

Read some of these, they may help:

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=3B56F

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

I don't know what your page is meant to look like but start with this basic idea and build your skills around it :)

```
#Header, #Content, #Footer{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}

#Header{
  height:100px;
  background:yellow;
}

#Content{
  height:400px;
  background:green;
}

#Footer{
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

and the html would be

```
<body>
 <div id="Header">Put your header stuff here.</div>
 <div id="Content">Put your content here.</div>
 <div id="Footer">Put your footer stuff here.</div>
</body>
```

Put the children inside the correct section and set their position to relative also.

Have a play with these and see how you get along. Spend as much time as you can really understanding positioning, once you have this as a solid foundation you'll find designing much easier!

Sorry if I'm not specific enough, I'm sure some other nice guy on SO will add to this and give you a hand if they have anything constructive to add :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :) If you'd be so kind, can you mark this answer as accepted. It may help some others in the same boat as you find an answer (and give me a bit of karma ;) ) Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Thanks so much @Mulliman. I wish I knew how to give Karma and label this question answered. But I'm having a hard time finding the links that let me do that.